# After update Xcode 4.4,didSelectRowAtIndexPath Not running

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode4

I updated Xcode 4.4 from 4.3. And I run a project at "iPhone 5.1 Simulator".
I could run a project. but I tap a tableCell Of UITableView.
So I added "NSLog()" to top of "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"method. but didn't display that log.
and I can't see to transit next view.

What can I do for tableView of transition?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"(NSInteger *)indexPath.row=%d", indexPath.row);    
    NextViewController *nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
    nextViewController.dicPatient = self.dicPatient;
    nextViewController.dicLoginKey = self.dicLoginKey;
    nextViewController.cellIdx = (NSInteger *)indexPath.row;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];

}
```

P.S.
The project made at Xcode 4.2.
Of course I did Clean&Build before the project ran. 
my OS is Lion

Answer (score 0):

Check these things.
In your header file

```
<UITableViewDelegate>
```

In your implementation file

```
your_table_view.delegate=self;
```

Or if you have added your tableView from interface builder then open your xib file. select your table and in the utilites bar click connections inspector and in the outlets section assign the delegate to File's Owner

Comment: Thanks!Neo.
And sorry,my words were not enough.
This project has InterfaceBuilder Object.(xib) And this UITableViewController's Outlets has "dataSource - File's Owner","delegate - File's Owner", Rerference's Outlets "view - File's Owner".
And this project ran at X-Code 4.3. (Before Updating X-Code 4.4)